# Getting "RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session" when I run for test accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_xs,
                                                          y: batch_ys})
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
            if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
                 print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost)) 


    print("Optimization Finished!")      

# Test model
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))

 # Calculate accuracy
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print("Testing accuracy:", sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: Do you know what with tf.Session() as sess does?

Answer (score 0):

Your session object is closed before your test model. So when you try to use sess in the last print statement it will throw you the Runtime error.

So, what you can do is:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    print("Testing accuracy:", sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```